# Airflow: access ti.xcom_pull() from templated SQL in PostgresOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I have a task, instantiated from a PostgresOperator like this:

```
sql = "select * from {{ ti.xcom_pull(key='foo') }};"
task = PostgresOperator(sql=sql)
```

the dag fails to load saying "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'ti' is undefined.

I get the same error when I replace 'ti' with task_instance.  Any help would be much appreciated!

The weird thing is if I replace `ti.xcom_pull(...)` with `ti` it renders with no complaint, returning `<TaskInstance: foo.bar 2019-04-25T14:27:06.822835+00:00 [None]>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it with: `{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='taskidwherexcomisset', key='foo').encode('utf-8')}}` but I am sure `{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='foo') }}` will work too.

try:

```
sql = 'select * from ' + "{{ti.xcom_pull(key='foo').encode('utf-8')}}" + ';',
```

example log line just to show it works:

```
[2019-04-25 15:39:24,715] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-04-25 15:39:24,714] {postgres_operator.py:52} INFO - Executing: select * from 2019/04/24/;
```